# Object pointed by boost::shared_ptr in base class is never destroyed

Tags: c++, ios, boost, shared-ptr, arm64

I have a weird problem with boost shared_ptr:

```
class A
{

    A( )
    : m_myObjectPtr( new MyObject( ) )
    {

    }

    protected:

    boost::shared_ptr<MyObject> m_myObjectPtr; // MyObject class is a simple class with a constructor and destructor
};

class B : A
{
    B( )
    {

    }

    void CleanMyObject( )
    {
        m_myObjectPtr.reset( );
    }
};

class MyObject
{
    MyObject( )
    {
        cout << "Constructed MyObject" << endl;
    }

    ~MyObject( )
    {
        cout << "Destroyed MyObject" << endl;
    }
};
```

My problem is that the destructor of MyObject is never invoked when I call B::CleanMyObject( ). "Destroyed MyObject" is never printed.

I am seeing this on iOS with arm64 build of boost 1_57 built using https://github.com/danoli3/ofxiOSBoost/blob/master/scripts/build-libc%2B%2B.sh

Any ideas?

Comment: `Class` is not a keyword in C++

Comment: Shared pointers are shared.  Are you (purposely or accidentally) copying your `A` or `B` objects anywhere?  Posting a complete example of creating and deleting the object would help.

Comment: This code is clearly not the code you were trying. There are several issues preventing it from even compiling the classes.

Comment: This is a made up example from a complex project, I am not able to get the   exact code here. But from what I inspected, MyObjectPtr is never referenced outside of classes A and B.

Comment: @ssk For questions like this, it is best if you can provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by @Josh Kelley's suggestion, using unique_ptr solved the problem for me.

So I diverted my attention to boost::shared_ptr to understand what is the problem. It turns out that building boost for iOS with flags BOOST_AC_USE_PTHREADS and BOOST_SP_USE_PTHREADS was the original reason for the oddity. Based on:

1) Answer by Andy Weinstein: [Boost threads: in IOS, thread_info object is being destructed before the thread finishes executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692802/boost-threads-in-ios-thread-info-object-is-being-destructed-before-the-thread)

2) Weakly ordered CPU tutorial (http://preshing.com/20121019/this-is-why-they-call-it-a-weakly-ordered-cpu/)

It was clear that I should be using Spin Lock i.e., BOOST_SP_USE_SPINLOCK flag for building boost.

The problem seems to be fixed after I rebuilt boost with BOOST_SP_USE_SPINLOCK flag.

Comment: Did you remove the BOOST_AC_USE_PTHREADS and BOOST_SP_USE_PTHREADS from the script when you added BOOST_SP_USE_SPINLOCK?

Comment: @Danoli3 Yes, I removed  BOOST_AC_USE_PTHREADS and BOOST_SP_USE_PTHREADS.

Comment: Awesome I've gone ahead and audited the Boost script as well and made this change for all the boost libs so no one else gets this issue ;)

Answer (score 3):

The obvious answer is that you have multiple `shared_ptr`s referring to a single object, so resetting one reduces the reference count but doesn't delete the object.

This can happen even if the `shared_ptr` isn't referenced outside of `A` and `B`. If you assign `A` or `B` without overloading `operator=` or copy `A` or `B` (e.g., pass by value, return by value) without overloading the copy constructor, then this will result.

There are several ways you could investigate.

- You could check [`boost::shared_ptr::use_count()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#use_count) within your `CleanMyObject` to see if it's greater than 1.
- If you don't want sharing and reference counting, you could replace `boost::shared_ptr` with `std::unique_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr`.
- If you want to make sure you're not accidentally copying or assigning `A` or `B`, you can derive `A` from [`boost::noncopyable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/core/doc/html/core/noncopyable.html).

Comment: Nice suggestions, let me post what I find. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

The following code illustrates a working example. It uses the `shared_ptr<T>` from std namespace starting in C++11, but you can substitute `boost::shared_ptr<T>`.

`MyObject::~MyObject` is invoked in the call to `B::CleanMyObject` as you are trying to do.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyObject
{
public:
    MyObject()
    {
        cout << "Constructed MyObject" << endl;
    }

    ~MyObject()
    {
        cout << "Destroyed MyObject" << endl;
    }
};

class A
{
protected:
    A()
    : m_myObjectPtr(new MyObject())
    {

    }

    std::shared_ptr<MyObject> m_myObjectPtr; // MyObject class is a simple class with a constructor and destructor
};

class B : A
{
public:
    B()
    {

    }
    void CleanMyObject()
    {
        m_myObjectPtr.reset();
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.CleanMyObject();
}
```

Comment: What if there was a bug in boost 1_57?

Comment: [First Rule of Programming](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/) it's always your fault.

Comment: @NickStrupat Thanks for the answer and confirmation