# App runs on simulator but not iPhone 6 plus

Tags: boost

I am porting a library (https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo) that was developed on Linux to iOS. The target device is the iPhone 6 plus. In a first step we managed to port it to Windows. In addition we succeeded to get it running on the xcode simulator for the iPhone. But when trying to launch it on the iPhone, the app crashes after few cycles with the following error:

malloc: *** error for object 0x12ce8c3d8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Even worse, the crash is not repeatable. Sometimes is crashes sooner sometimes later. Since it runs just fine in the simulator we cannot use Memory Management tools like 'Guard Malloc'. We tried the 'Leaks' and 'Zombies' Instruments without any success.

We are aware of the fact that the iPhone uses the ARM_NEON instruction set whereas on the Mac Book we have SSE2. Could that be a problem? 
Furthermore, the library depends on Boost threads. Is it possibly a multithreading issue? What makes it crash on the device but not in the simulator? Are we potentially missing a very basic point?

Thanks in advance! Looking forward for replies :)

Comment: I am using iOS 9.1 and Xcode 7.1..

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You must compile Boost for iOS with the following flag

> -DBOOST_SP_USE_SPINLOCK

You can my boost compile script here with the flag already set:
https://github.com/danoli3/ofxiOSBoost/tree/master/scripts

More information on this Boost Threads issue here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14738583/1676524

A full break down of the problem on this blog: http://preshing.com/20121019/this-is-why-they-call-it-a-weakly-ordered-cpu/