# Why is that using Boost on iOS crashed in release mode, but not int debug

Tags: ios, multithreading, boost, crash, release

When I use boost.asio, boost.thread and etc on iOS platform, the app crashed int release mode but works well int debug mode. I fix the release runtime bugs as I descibed at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18286624/653114).

My Question Is:
Why is everything ok in debug-mode? The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4245821/653114) seems to say that the crash is caused by thumb flag. The debug-mode compiler should use "thumb" flag as same as release mode, ant I wonder the app should also crash in debug-mode because of using thumb, which confuses me.

**UPDATE:**
Here is my code of using asio:

Params are declared as the private member of the CrossPlatformAPI:

```
boost::recursive_mutex m_mutex;
boost::asio::io_service m_ioService;
boost::scoped_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> m_idleWork;
boost::scoped_ptr<boost::thread> m_mainThread;
```

First, I post two async-tasks by calling CrossPlatformAPI::Init in the main thread:

```
int CrossPlatformAPI::Init(const P2PInitParam& oInitParam)
{
    boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
    m_idleWork.reset(new boost::asio::io_service::work(m_ioService));
    m_mainThread.reset(new boost::thread(boost::bind( &boost::asio::io_service::run, &m_ioService)));
    std::string strLog(oInitParam.szAppDataDir);
    m_ioService.post(boost::bind( &CrossPlatformAPI::HandleLog, this, strLog));
    m_ioService.post(boost::bind( &CrossPlatformAPI::HandleInit, this, oInitParam)); 
    return 0;
}
```

Second, CrossPlatformAPI::HandleLog and CrossPlatformAPI::HandleInit handle the async-task:

```
void CrossPlatformAPI::HandleLog(std::string & log)
{
    std::cout << log << std::endl;
}

void CrossPlatformAPI::HandleInit(P2PInitParam& oInitParam)
{
    try
    {
        //Init
        //...
    }
    catch (std::exception&)
    {
    }

    return;
}
```

I have tried using boost:ref to wrap the binding param instead of binding directly, then the app doesn't crash. Why not? And what also confuses me is that if the bind param type is std::string, the param that the handle function received is incorrect when wrapped by std::ref. It seems that std::string without using std::ref works well: didn't crash and the value recived is correct, but not the sruct-type param, like  **P2PInitParam**.

**UPDATE2**:

```
int CrossPlatformAPI::Init(const P2PInitParam& oInitParam)
{
    boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
    m_idleWork.reset(new boost::asio::io_service::work(m_ioService));
    m_mainThread.reset(new boost::thread(boost::bind( &boost::asio::io_service::run, &m_ioService)));
    std::string strLog(oInitParam.szAppDataDir);
    m_ioService.post(boost::bind( &CrossPlatformAPI::HandleLog, this, boost::cref(strLog))); // OK
    m_ioService.post(boost::bind( &CrossPlatformAPI::HandleInit, this, boost::cref(oInitParam))); // Crash
    return 0;
}

void CrossPlatformAPI::HandleLog(const std::string& log)
{
    std::cout << log << std::endl;
}

void CrossPlatformAPI::HandleInit(const P2PInitParam& oInitParam)
{
    try
    {
        //Init
        //...
    }
    catch (std::exception&)
    {
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: 99.99% of the time, apps that work in one mode, but not in another, have critically bad bugs that just get covered up in the mode that's working because the dodgy overwrite/overflow/whatever happens to not corrupt anything vital.

Comment: What iOS/XCode/Boost version do you use? Anyway, according to the backtrace, it's most likely object life-time issues: perhaps, your completion handler is bound to an object that doesn't outlive the acync. operation.

Comment: ios6.1, xcode 4.6, boost 1.53. The bug of release mode dismissed when I  added “-mno-thumb” compile flag. It didn't seem to be object life-time issue or the code issue, and the simulator run the release-built app well not the device when I didn't add "-mno-thumb". I think boost doesn't support xcode's default compile setting well since it doesn't support thumb instructions, doesn't it?

Comment: Hi @IgorR., I find that it also works well if I change the optimize level from "-Os" to "NONE" instead of added “-mno-thumb”. It should be the optimize issue. Can you give me an advice when using shard_ptr, thread, asio on IOS?

Comment: By the way, I bind my "completion handler" to a global static object that exists at the whole time when the app is running.

Comment: @Kenny Chang As far as I remember, I build my iOS app (with Boost.Asio, Boost.Thread and all the stuff) in thumb mode without any issue, but I'll double check this tomorrow. Besides, the fact that your crash depends on the optimization level somewhat confirms my guess that the problem is in your code. But you haven't shown any code, so it's quite difficult to make any further assumptions... Perhaps, you access asio objects from multiple threads?

Comment: Thanks a lot @IgorR., I just updated my question with adding the code.

Comment: You can't pass parameters by reference like this, you should always wrap them with `ref`. Currently you take by reference a temporary copy of your params stored within the functor created by `boost::bind`. By the way, make sure that you really mean to pass by reference (maybe you meant `const &`?)

Comment: My function Prototype should be : bool Init(const P2PInitParam& param);void HandleInit(const P2PInitParam& param); And why is that wrapping parameters with ref ok? I didn't wrap std::string param, but it was ok.

Comment: Hi @IgorR. Look at Update2 please. Is it the correct usage as you suggested above?

Comment: If the function accepts a parameter by `const &` - bind it by value, without `ref` or `cref`. In **Update2** you actually store a reference to a locale object, which eventually causes crash.

Comment: @IgorR.If I pass(bind) all parameters by (const &) and make the functions accepting parameters by (const &), it comes to the original bug. Changing optimization level to -O0 can avoid it.

Comment: @Kenny Chang I don't understand what you mean by saying " I pass(bind) all parameters by (const &) ". Assume, you have a function `f(const string &s);` Bind the actual parameter like this: `string someString; bind(&f, someString);` OTOH, if you've got `f(string &s)`, bind like this: `bind(&f, ref(someString))` - but take care of `someString` lifetime!

Comment: @IgorR.Finally, I found that it was the issue of the parameter's lifetime! :(
Thanks a lot.:)